# re-rolling a random number in swift

Tags: swift, random, colors

So, while working in swift, i made a view in a viewController where when I tap another view in the same ViewController, it generates an array with value

```
[arc4random_uniform(257), arc4random_uniform(257), arc4random_uniform(257)]
```

where the random numbers are parameters for random RBG colors, and I've only sort-of made it work. I want it so that every time the user (or me ;_;) taps on the view with the Tap Gesture Recognizer, it generates another random color. I don't really know how to "re-roll" the Array so that it generates another random color.

Comment: Try wrapping this in a function or closure, such as: `func randomRGB() -> (Float, Float, Float) { return (arc4random_uniform(256), arc4random_uniform(256), arc4random_uniform(256))}`, and assigning your property to the result of calling that.

Comment: Also, your `arc4random_uniform` call should have 256 as a maximum value, to get a range of values from 0 to 255.

Comment: oh yeah, lol i thought rgb was 256 instead of 255 >.<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get just a random `UIColor`, you can create a function which gets called everytime you touch the recognizer. Also, as mattt mentioned in the comments, you should change the max value from `257` to `256`.

```
func randomColorCreator()->UIColor{
    var red:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))/CGFloat(255)
    var green:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))/CGFloat(255)
    var blue:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256))/CGFloat(255)
    return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

If you really want to get the three color-values, you can return the three values like that:

```
func randomColorCreatorV2()->(red:Int, green:Int, blue:Int){
    var red: = arc4random_uniform(256)
    var green: = arc4random_uniform(256)
    var blue: = arc4random_uniform(256)
    return (red, green, blue)
}
```

You than access the values like that in your `TapGestureRecognizer` method:

```
var randomColors = randomColorCreatorV2()
var blueValue = randomColors.blue
```